# How to tweak Solr Matching Parameters?

Tags: search, solr, lucene, matching

I'm using Solr for the search component of my application, and am looking to play around with different factors to see how it affects results.

Specifically Solr docs make mention of the basic scoring factors:

- tf --> term frequency
- idf --> inverse document frequency
- coord --> coordination factor
- lengthNorm --> matches based on length of field

Could anyone tell me how to "adjust" whatever numerical factors are being used for these values? (If that's possible, haven't found much documentation saying ye or ney)

After I've played around with these I'll move on to methods such as boosting and so on.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with the [Custom Similarity](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins#Similarity) class.
This would allow you to modify the above parameters and scoring factors.

Check the [lucene DefaultSimilarity](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/lucene/src/java/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/DefaultSimilarity.java) class for reference which is the actual implementation.

Comment: Here is a little more guidance on what you would need to implement a custom similarity class - http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_4_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/package-summary.html#changingSimilarity